# how i can use this.value in click function other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

this.value is now $("#style_background"), i need to change it to $(".selector") value. How can i do this.

```
$("#style_background").click(function(){

    if ($(".selector").is(":checked")) {

        document.cookie = "background=" + this.value + ";" + "path=/";
        disable($('#style_background'));            
        notification('success', 'record updated successfuly', 'topRight');

    } else {

        disable($('#style_background'));            
        notification('alert', 'restart your browser', 'topRight');

    }
});
```

Comment: write the code as a function passing a dom element as the param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#style_background").click((function(){

    if ($(".selector").is(":checked")) {

        document.cookie = "background=" + this.value + ";" + "path=/";
        disable($('#style_background'));            
        notification('success', 'record updated successfuly', 'topRight');

    } else {

        disable($('#style_background'));            
        notification('alert', 'restart your browser', 'topRight');

    }
}).bind($(".selector")[0]));
```

You might want to use the [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function in order to specify the 'this' value inside the function.

Comment: You probably meant to `bind` to `$(".selector")[0]`, not to a jQuery context

Comment: I have 8 class with .selector. This is only gets the first ones value. I have to use with this.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to trigger the checkbox from html. (If you'd provide too this code it would be better):

```
$(".selector").change(function(){
   if ($(".selector").is(":checked")) {
       document.cookie = "background=" + this.value + ";" + "path=/";
       disable($('#style_background'));            
       notification('success', 'record updated successfuly', 'topRight');
   } else {
       disable($('#style_background'));            
       notification('alert', 'restart your browser', 'topRight');
   }
});
```

Comment: I have 8 backgrounds and i have a save button. I have to use it with #style_background